# Azure AD authentication with .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to different Azure services from my C# code which uses .NET Framework 4.7.2 on-premise application. Is there a way to do Azure AD authentication from within my C# code to connect to an Azure File Share for instance? (*https://azurestorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/afs/test.txt*).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to connect to your File Share Service using Azure AD i.e; managed identity at least with azure SDK version 12.8.0  as you can check constructor options available for [ShareServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet) are limited to that.Currently, you can only use the access key to connect your azure file.

You acn use (SAS)Shared Access Signature, or  Storage Account Name/Key or specify Storage Account connection string to connect to your File Service.

Azure Files supports identity-based authentication over Server Message Block (SMB) through on-premises Active Directory Domain Services [(AD DS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/virtual-dc/active-directory-domain-services-overview) and Azure Active Directory Domain Services [(Azure AD DS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview) .
See how to [Enable Azure Active Directory Domain Services authentication on Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable?tabs=azure-portal) in portal.

You can check some [Faq regarding azure ad here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#ad-ds--azure-ad-ds-authentication)

You can raise a feature request over [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/b09330d1-c625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c).

**References:**

1. [dotnet api-azure/storage.files.shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme)
2. [Using c# for azure file storage sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-file-storage-in-c-sharp/)